# How to translate "is he a cannibal"?

Tags: traducción

I entered this into Google translate:

> the pope eats spuds*; is he a cannibal?

...and got:

> el Papa come papas; es que un caníbal?

Is this right, "que"? Should it be, "es **el** un caníbal?" o algo distinto?

- If I enter "potatoes" I get "patatas"

Comment: It's an untranslatable joke: "El _Papa_ come _papas_... ¿es él un caníbal?". Papas = patatas = potatoes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You have 2 ways:

> 1. ¿Es él un caníbal?
> 2. ¿Es un caníbal?

Second option is preferred because you already know who you're referring to.

Comment: Could you say ¿Es caníbal? I feel sure I have heard similar usage but perhaps my memory is at fault here.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, actually the article can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep que `que` to introduce a subordinate sentence, but you need a verb for that subordinate sentence.

> El Papa come papas. ¿Es que un caníbal? (wrong)
>
> El Papa come papas; ¿es que (él) **es** un caníbal? (pronoun could go before or after the second "es")

This `que` could be switched for `acaso` or "por casualidad", and then you won't need the verb

> el Papa come papas. ¿Es *acaso* un caníbal? (or "¿*Acaso* es un caníbal?")
>
> el Papa come papas. ¿Es *por casualidad* un caníbal?

Because `que` can be used a conjunction to introduce subordinate sentences (see apt 2 [here](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW)). `Acaso` works as a conjunction too. In this case you can have only one "es" and this will belong to the subordinate sentence. In the "que" case you need two, one for the subordinate and one for the main sentence.